# How to check a condition inside select box option in reactive forms using angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, multi-select

I tried to display options of a multi select box after evaluating two conditions in ngIf. Code is given below.

```
<select multiple class="form-control multi-select" formControlName="products">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let per of productList" >
     <ng-container *ngFor="let cper of cartproductList">    
       <option *ngIf="(per.cart_id === 'cart1') && (per.id !== cper.cart_id)" [ngValue]="per.id" > 
         {{per.name}}
       </option>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
 </select>
```

I am getting the values two times. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Can you tell me what is `productList` and `cartproductList` ? And what you actually expect as an output?

Comment: Are you sure your mark-up is correct? cartproductList isn't relating to anything of the above loop for productList. Are you sure it shouldn't be "let cper of per.cartproductList"?